# Wrong MapReduce result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a Collection with many columns: col1,col2, WebsiteCode, CreatedDate, col3....,coln.

I want to group by WebsiteCode in a range of CreatedDate.

So I do:

map :

```
function Map() {
         var key={WebsiteCode:this.WebsiteCode};
         val={Count: 1};
         emit(key,val);
 }
```

reduce :

```
function Reduce(key, values) {
var res = {Total:0};
values.forEach(function(value) {
res.Total += value.Count;
});
return res;
}
```

And query range DateTime:

`{ "CreatedDate" : { "$gte" : dateFrom , "$lte" : dateTo } }`

Finally, I run this mapreduce command.
The result returns not what I expected with many rows having `Total = NaN`
Ex: `{_id:{WebsiteCode:"websitecode1"}}, {value:{Total:NaN}}`

But when I run count command:

`db.collect.find({ "WebsiteCode" : "websitecode1", "CreatedDate" : { "$gte" : dateFrom), "$lte" : dateTo } }).count();`

Result return: **927**

Could you explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reduce function must return a value that has the same shape as the emitted values.  So you can't use `Count` in the map and `Total` in the reduce.

Try this instead:

```js
function Reduce(key, values) {
    var res = {Count:0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        res.Count += value.Count;
    });
    return res;
}
```